# Tooltips in panels

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Seems like tooltips that you get from attribute `title="test"` are not displayed inside the panel.

Tested also with [stackoverflow loaded in the panel](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1053193/latest/), no tooltips when you hover mouse over hot, week, month. But the custom tooltips work, e.g. when you hover over tags.

Is there a way to enable tooltips in Add-on SDK panels, or the only way is going custom tooltips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, displaying tooltips for HTML elements requires [special code in the browser](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/0e2cc686b07b/browser/base/content/browser.js#l3090). This code is there for the built-in browser but not for the browser that the SDK embeds in a panel. That's something that might be worth filing as an SDK bug but in the meantime - custom tooltips are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way.
This works since Firefox 31

```js
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    contentURL: "http://stackoverflow.com/",
});

panel.show();

require('sdk/view/core').getActiveView(panel)
    .setAttribute('tooltip', 'aHTMLTooltip');
```